# Creating directed graph from dictionary with scores

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this dictionary:

```
d1={
'a':['b','c','b'],
'b':['a','d','e']
}
```

it is sort of a directed graph. For example, d1['a'] points twice to 'b', and once to 'c' (see graph below)

[image]

What I want is to create two dictionaries out of d1 - pointing_to and pointed_by with values describing how many times they are pointing to or pointed by, respectively.

```
pointing_to={
'a':{'b':2,'c':1},
'b':{'a':1,'d':1,'e':1},
}

pointed_by={
'a':{'b':1},
'b':{'a':2},
'c':{'a':1},
'd':{'b':1},
'e':{'b':1}
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the `2` from? `{'b','c','b'}` is the same as `{'b','c'}`, so counting won't help.

Comment: @schwobaseggl , in d1['a'], it has 2 b's inside, so, in pointing_to 'a':{'b':2,...}. And image corresponds to d1. Pointing_to is basically count of number of values in d1

Comment: @EricKlaus `{'b','c','b'}` is a [`set`](https://www.python-course.eu/sets_frozensets.php), which in Python does not contain duplicate values.

Comment: @Ajax1234, my bad. Edited the post. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use some [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) utils to get to your output:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

d1 = {'a': ['b', 'c', 'b'], 'b': ['a', 'd', 'e']}

pointed_to = {k: Counter(v) for k, v in d1.items()}
pointed_from = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in pointed_to.items():
    for k_, v_ in v.items():
        pointed_from[k_][k] = v_

# pointed_to
{'a': Counter({'b': 2, 'c': 1}), 
 'b': Counter({'d': 1, 'a': 1, 'e': 1})}

# pointed_from
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'d': {'b': 1}, 
                             'a': {'b': 1}, 
                             'c': {'a': 1}, 
                             'b': {'a': 2}, 
                             'e': {'b': 1}})
```

Note that both `Counter` and `deafultdict` are subclasses of `dict`, so these two can, for all intents and purposes, be used as your desired output dicts.

If you really want `dict` objects, you can easily do that:

```
pointed_to = {k: dict(v) for k, v in pointed_to.items()}
pointed_from = dict(pointed_from)
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to make pointed_to and pointed_from dictionaries? I tried dict(pointed_to), it didn't work. I just want to eliminate 'Counter' term there

Comment: @EricKlaus As stated in the answer, the `Counter/defaultdict` objects **are** dictionaries (don't get distracted by their string representation). You can, of course, cast them if you want. Added that.